# A question about Fourier transform of tempered distribution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

I have a function $V\in W^{1,1}_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^+)$, for $y\in\mathbb{R}^+$, is true that: $V(\cdot,y)\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, i.e. $V(\cdot,y)$ is a distribution over $\mathbb{R}$? I have no idea on how to prove this statement. Let $\mathcal{F}\colon\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)\to\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the Fourier transform, i don't know how to prove the following two identities:
$$ \mathcal{F}(\partial_jV(\cdot,y))=i\xi_j\mathcal{F}(V(\cdot,y)),\quad\forall j=1,...,n,\tag{1}$$
and:
$$ \mathcal{F}(\partial_y V(\cdot,y))=\partial_y\mathcal{F}(V(\cdot,y)).\tag{2}$$
If i prove that $V(\cdot,y)\in\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then (1) follow from the well known properties of fourier transform. For (2) i have no idea on how to prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any $C^\infty$ function is in $W^{1,1}_{loc}$.

Comment: So? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Say $g\ge0$ is a smooth function on $\Bbb R^n$ which grows too fast at infinity to be a tempered distribution. Let $V(x,y)=g(x)$; then $V$ is a counterexample; $V(\cdot,0)\notin S'$.

Comment: Ok, in your opinion, there is another way to justify (1) and (2) with $V\in W^{1,1}_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^+)$?

Comment: It's clearly impossible to justify (1), since the Fourier transform mentioned in (1) need not even exist!

Comment: So there is a mistake in lemma 4.1.9 at page 121 in [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.00953.pdf) or may be i don't understand. Can you help me please

Comment: Although I add the hypothesis that $V(x,0)=u(x)$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, with $u\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, (1) is false?

Comment: Adding that hypothesis doesn't show $V(\cdot, y)\in S'$ for $y>0$.

Comment: And if i suppose that $\partial_{x_j}V(\cdot,y),\partial_yV(\cdot,y)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, there is a way to prove (1) and (2) with this hypothesis?

Comment: @  David C. Ullrich if i suppose that: $$\partial_{x_j}V(\cdot,y),\partial_y V(\cdot,y), V(\cdot,y)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$$, for a.e. $y>0$, there is a way to prove (1) and (2)? Please, help me.